# Any function in R same like PROC OPTMODEL in SAS?

Tags: r, sas

Do you know if there is any R package or function could help solve 
     "min y=x^3 - 3*x^2 + 4" 
like the following SAS code?

```
proc optmodel;      
   var x;
   min y=x**3 - 3*x**2 + 4;
 solve;
 print x;
 quit;
```

PROC OPTMODEL is documented here:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/ormpug/67517/HTML/default/viewer.htm#ormpug_optmodel_toc.htm

I am looking for the value of x that minimizes y.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is `optimize(function(x)x^3 - 3*x^2 + 4, interval=c(0, 5))` not good enough?

Comment: no... x = -inf for min(y), but I cant get it using any R function.

Comment: I wonder what would your desired output be like, since y doesn't have `min` on that interval.

Comment: hm in this case I would want R tell me that.

Comment: Would you mind showing the output from `SAS`

Comment: sorry but I dont have it...

Comment: The output from the solver in SAS (assuming you turn on multi-start  in attempt to get out of the local min at (x,y) (2,0)) will be (-5,957,051 , -2.113947e20).  The iteration after that in the solver pushes y past DBL_MIN, the solver stops are reports the problem as unbounded.

Comment: In the question title, you're asking if there's an R function akin to `proc optmodel`, but in your comment you said you can't get the answer using any R function. Are you not _allowed_ to use an R function, i.e. you have to write your own, or have you simply not found a suitable one?

Comment: Thx and I m sorry for not replying quickly. I want to find the argmin solution by any methods(any R function or write a function by myself...) but I need some hints.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the roots of a polynomial.  The R function to do this is `polyroot()`.  The argument to `polyroot()` is a vector of polynomial coefficients, arranged in increasing order.  Try this:

```
polyroot(c(4, 0, -3, 1))
[1] -1+0i  2-0i  2+0i
```

Now you can use this information to visualuse the polynomial, by setting the plot range of `curve()`:

```
curve(x^3 - 3*x^2 + 4, from=-2, to=3, col="blue")
abline(h=0)
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what `proc optmodel` does, but unless you feed `polyroot` with the FOCs it doesn't locate the optimal points. `polyroot(c(0, -6, 3))`

Comment: Hi, Thx. Sorry that I did not make myself clear. I am not only looking for root but also for the value of x that minimizes y.

Comment: This doesn't address the question. The OP is looking for minima, i.e. the values of `x` for which `y` is at a global or local minimum, not the roots, which are the values of `x` for which `y` vanishes.